# Bitmap changes the quality that is sent to my intent. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, bitmap

I was trying to upload an image in the facebook however, when it is about to be posted the image gets pixelized but when the post has been successful the image if not pixelized and it is the right image. How can I fix image that will be sent to facebook's upload picture?

```
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), img2[res2]);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/LatestShare.jpg";
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file=new File(path);
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    path=file.getPath();
    Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://"+path);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not process the image. Right now you are decoding the image, then re-encoding it as a JPEG.

Instead, use `openRawResource()` on `Resources()` to get an `InputStream` on the resource, then copy that content to a `FileOutputStream` using ordinary Java file I/O. Be sure to `flush()`, `getFD().sync()`, and `close()` the `FileOutputStream` when you are done.

Then, make sure that the MIME type in the `shareIntent` matches the actual MIME type of the drawable resource. If your resource is a JPEG, what you have now will be fine.

Also:

- Do not use concatenation to create a file path. Use `File` constructors. This ensures that you handle directory separators properly.
- Use `Uri.fromFile()` to convert a `File` to a `Uri`, not string concatenation.
- Unless you think that the user wants this image to be alongside the rest of their photos, do not use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. Instead, use `getExternalCacheDir()` (available on `Context`), so you do not clutter up the user's gallery, etc.

However, in the end, your bitmap quality is only partially controlled by you. The app that you are sending it to is welcome to do whatever it wants with the bitmap, and "whatever it wants" may affect the quality. There is nothing you can do about this, other than file bug reports with the other app's authors.

Another, more complex possibility is for you to implement a streaming `ContentProvider`, to save you from writing the data to a file on external storage and therefore expecting third-party apps to have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as a permission.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer :) I guess I will not just use bitmap. I'll just get the directory of the photo I want to upload and shareintent it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a resource ID (of an image file), that you are trying to get the image file from.

[resources.getResourceName(ID)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29) takes an ID and returns a string representation of the filename.

Let us use this information. Since, we need have the resource ID and need to get the URI,

```
Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                context.getResources().getResourcePackageName(resourceID) + '/' +
                context.getResources().getResourceTypeName(resourceID) + '/' +
                context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceID) );
```

should give the URI. There might be small corrections needed in places. Please feel free to edit my answer to reflect the same.

No compression required. Yay!

Did that help?

Comment: Hi thank you for answering my question, could you please give me an example? I got confused on placing the codes you suggested.

Comment: Resources are not files on the Android filesystem, so I fail to see how this will be useful.

Comment: @CommonsWare As per the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29), decodeResource(Resources res, int id) takes the " The resources object containing the image data" and the " The resource id of the image data". getResourceName() takes a resource ID and returns a string of the form "package:type/entry". I am editing my post to include a more complete answer

Comment: @codesofdave, CommonsWare Updated my answer. Please feel free to make edits/comments.

Comment: Third-party apps rarely recognize the `android.resource` `Uri` scheme. Ideally, more would support it. Since many do not, this approach will tend to lead to a lot of incompatibilities.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yea yea, I understand what you are saying. I saw your answer. I guess, if this doesn't work for the OP, that would obviously be the way to go, since it takes away many potential compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this send bitmap directory using intent

```
Bitmap  photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
         Bitmap  imageBitmap= ReSizeBitmap.getResizedBitmap(photo, 300, 300);
```

And send bitmap object Directly using `shareIntent.putParceble(imageBitmap)`

Comment: Hi thank you for answering my question, could you please give me an example? I got confused on placing the codes you suggested.

Comment: Note that this will only work for small bitmaps. An `Intent` needs to be under 1MB.

Comment: I don't get why you are suggesting the OP to resize the photo.

Comment: it is working for me upto 3 MB tried it not sure above it will work or not.

Comment: The OP did not suggest any resizing constraints. Your implementation forces the image to be resized to 300x300. I do not see how that can be acceptable.

Comment: That is because you are resizing the photo to 300x300, which will keep it under the 1MB limit. However, this approach cannot be used for sharing larger images without resizing.

Answer (score 0):

*I was trying to upload an image in the facebook however, when it is about to be posted the image gets pixelized but when the post has been successful the image if not pixelized and it is the right image. How can I fix image that will be sent to facebook's upload picture?*

The image get pixelized by Facebook when you are posting the image? There is nothing wrong with that, that's how they designed it to work. There is nothing you can do from your end